# Sending Facebook messages through their API - possible?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm building a web app for a client where members of general public can create an account. Client would like to be able to use my app to send Facebook messages to those members.

Note that my app is a standard LAMP site and NOT a facebook application, nor is there the desire to create one; delivering messages to members' FB inbox is the only goal.

Is this possible, using the FB API or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

In short the answer is **no**. Facebook do not give you the ability to do this to prevent spam. You could post to all of your user's feeds however?

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do is:

- Register facebook app to get access to FB API. You don't need to have actual facebook app, just use received API key on your standalone site.
- Create [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) process on your site so users would be able to connect with your site through facebook.
- Ask users for additional [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) during authentication to access their email, as it is not something that could be accessed without user's explicit permission.

That's the bare minimum for this task.

Comment: You cannot send messages through the api. The extended permission "email" allows you to access their email address so you can send them a regular (non-facebook) email.